# C# Runtime cast failure of constrained generic type to constraint type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I'm running into a runtime casting error with code analogous to the following. First I have an interface with a visitor pattern set up:

```
public interface IAnimalVisitor<out T>
{
    T Visit(Dog a);
    T Visit(Cat a);
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }

    T Accept<T>(IAnimalVisitor<T> v);
}

public abstract class AnimalBase : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; }

    protected AnimalBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public abstract T Accept<T>(IAnimalVisitor<T> v);
}

public class Dog : AnimalBase
{
    public Dog(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override T Accept<T>(IAnimalVisitor<T> v)
    {
        return v.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Cat : AnimalBase
{
    public Cat(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override T Accept<T>(IAnimalVisitor<T> v)
    {
        return v.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Then a class implementing the visitor pattern (hidden as a nested class):

```
public class AnimalSpeaker
{
    private class SpeakerVisitor : IAnimalVisitor<string>
    {
        public string Visit(Dog a)
        {
            return "Woof";
        }

        public string Visit(Cat a)
        {
            return "Meow";
        }
    }

    private readonly SpeakerVisitor _SpeakerVisitor = new SpeakerVisitor();

    public string Speak(IAnimal a)
    {
        return a.Accept(_SpeakerVisitor);
    }
}
```

And finally I have a generic class constrained to consume types of IAnimals, which passes an instance to the visitor through its encapsulating class:

```
public abstract class AnimalSignTextBuilderBase<TAnimal>
    where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    private readonly AnimalSpeaker _AnimalSpeaker = new AnimalSpeaker();

    public string BuildSignText(TAnimal a)
    {
        var spokenText = _AnimalSpeaker.Speak(a);
        return $"{a.Name} says {spokenText}.";
    }
}

public class DogSignTextBuilder : AnimalSignTextBuilderBase<Dog> { }
public class CatSignTextBuilder : AnimalSignTextBuilderBase<Cat> { }
```

This code compiles perfectly fine, but at runtime (it's called from an ASP.net request) when I call

```
new DogSignTextBuilder().BuildSignText(new Dog("Fido"))
```

I get an invalid cast exception. This is caused by calling `_AnimalSpeaker.Speak(a)`.

I have no idea why this would throw. What's more, I can debug the code in Visual Studio and enter `a is IAnimal` in the immediate window, resulting in `true`. I can also enter `_AnimalSpeaker.Speak(a)` in the immediate window and it results in the following error:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TAnimal' to 'IAnimal'
```

I can also take this example and post it in dotnetfiddle and have it work fine, so at this point I'm at a total loss for ideas on what's going on.

**Edit:** I also found that just calling `a.Name` in the immediate window fails due to:

```
error CS1061: 'TAnimal' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'TAnimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I checked my references and they're all there. So far it just seems like the generic constraint is being ignored at runtime. I can also enter `(a as IAnimal).Name`, which correctly returns `Fido`.

Comment: Are you able to reduce at all to a minimal example? I wouldn't have thought we'd need all that code just to show the problem.

Comment: Although your claim that it's an *exception* doesn't really fit in well with "error CS1503" which is a compiler error...

Comment: I added an edit after finding a little more information that suggests the rest of the code is a red herring. I wanted to have as complete as I could given that this makes no sense to me.

Comment: You have two classes `AnimalSignTextBuilder<>` and `AnimalSignTextBuilderBase<>` are you sure you're using right class to derive `DogSignTextBuilder`?

Comment: @vendettamit Typo. There's only AnimalSignTextBuilderbase<>

Comment: Well, then it should work as expected. I added a `setter` to name property and made `speak()` public and fiddle is happy with your code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/J0HAon

Comment: @JonSkeet Also bad wording on my part. The actual runtime exception I get is an InvalidCastException. Entering the same method call in the immediate window results in the compiler exception. Editted for correctness/clarity.

Comment: I suspect the immediate window is a red herring. Stick to what can be compiled and run - but it would *really* help to have a [mcve].

Comment: I copied all of your code into VS and tried running it. `new DogSignTextBuilder().BuildSignText(new Dog("Fido"))` outputs "Fido says Woof." No error.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue completely unrelated to everything I thought it was related to. The short of it is that a delegate was failing to cast a value properly, not the generic input.